# How implement 'changes' abstraction?

Tags: scala, types

I have some functions that work with database and for each of this functions, I'm logging some info about changes.

It's done like this:

```
case class DBResult[T](result: T, Seq[String])

trait DiffableBy[T] {
  def -(old: T): Seq[String]
}

case class B1(..) extends DiffableBy[A1]
case class A1(..)

def f(..): DBResult[Result, Seq[String]] = {
  ..
  val before = B1(..)
  val after = A1(..)
  futureRes.map(res => DBResult(res, before - after)
}
```

for a lot of different functions. And when I call `f` function it easy to write log or so, but this logs is plain strings and calculated in one manner.

But now I want to find the difference between them in different ways. For example, assume two case classes `b` and `a`. When one fields different between them do log, when other — send email, etc.

It can be done like this:

```
trait Before
trait After
case class BeforeAndAfter(before: Before, after: After)

case class B1(..) extends Before
case class A1(..) extends After

case class DBResult[T](result: T, beforeAndAfter: BeforeAndAfter) 

def f(..): DBResult[Result, BeforeAndAfter] = {
  ..
  val before = B1(..)
  val after = A1(..)
  futureRes.map(res => DBResult(res, BeforeAndAfter(before, after))
}
.. // many more functions like f

// and then use it like this

case class EmailChanges(..)
case class LogChanges(..)

def ExtractEmailDiff(beforeAndAfter: BeforeAndAfter): Seq[EmailDiff] = 
  beforeAndAfter match {
    case BeforeAndAfter(b: B1, a: A1) => { .. }
    case BeforeAndAfter(b: B2, a: A2) => { .. }
    case _ => Seq.empty[EmailDiff]
  }

def ExtractLogDiff(beforeAndAfter: BeforeAndAfter): Seq[LogDiff] = 
  beforeAndAfter match {
    case BeforeAndAfter(b: B3, a: A3) => { .. }
    case BeforeAndAfter(b: B4, a: A4) => { .. }
    case _ => Seq.empty[LogDiff]
  }
```

But I don't really like pattern matching here as it is easy to forget to cover some cases. Are there easier or/and better ways to do this?

Comment: Yevhenii, it is not clear who else except for pattern-matching logic knows which actions are applicable to which differences. So it is not clear what you ask for. Could you describe how your "perfect world" solution would look like? Do you mean you prefer the logic to be inside each `B1`, `B2`, ... classes?

Comment: `it is easy to forget to cover some cases` - It will remain true irrespective of the programming tool that you use. But, if you design your types more cleverly then compiler can help by making sure that your matches are exhaustive. The answer is hidden in `types`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, if you have a reasonably simple solution to force the compiler to check for completeness of the pattern matching that will treat `case (A1, B1)` + `case (A2,B2)` + `case (A3,B3)` as a complete match without specifying impossible from the business logic point of view cases such as `case (A1,B2)`, it would be interesting to see such a solution or at least an idea of that. I see only one idea and I don't like it.

Comment: @SergGr I don't see any simple solution which with work with current type hierarchy. That is why I mentioned that OP should express more focus and control in the abstraction design, only then compiler can help.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, I'm not the OP so my question is more theoretical. Still assuming you have control over the type hierarchy, what would you suggest? I still don't see any reasonably simple solutions that will not introduce a duplication of business logic.